# Upgrade to Wheezy - CUPS printing to lpd printers is 6x slower

Tags: linux, printing, debian-wheezy, cups, ghostscript

We have Debian Squeeze 32-bit servers that print PDFs to Xerox DocuColor printers.  The PDFs are processed in about six seconds.

We are in the process of upgrading our servers to Wheezy 64-bit. We can print documents, but the same documents take about 36 seconds to print. This is bad, because we print hundreds of documents at a time.

We've looked over the documentation for CUPS, experimented with the fitplot settings (anabling/disabling), updated to the latest PPDs, and changed the default pdftops renderer from gs to pdftops but have not been able to fix this.

We're at a loss as to how to diagnose and fix this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Likely a [ghostscript issue...](http://serverfault.com/questions/381013/shell-command-slow-when-using-pipe-fast-with-intermediate-file/381048#381048) - Would you be able to run this from the command line (`lp -d printer name file.pdf`) and possibly pull an `strace` of the process?

Comment: The lp command runs quickly. It's the daemon that processes the file that takes so long. How do I strace that?

Comment: Note that looking at the process list, the slowdown does appear to be ghostscript processing the file. Any suggestions on how to improve this?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with "pdf2ps". I've tried setting the default renderer to "pdftops" which is faster, but printing seems to ignore the setting.

Comment: So now you can do this with a raw file. Run `pdf2ps` with a representative file...

Comment: I've compared pdf2ps and pdftops, and the former is what is so slow. So how can I tell cups to use the latter?

Comment: See my update below.

Comment: Printing is fast when I first run pdftops on the file and print the resulting ps directly. Will look into that.

Answer (score 1):

So this is probably an issue with the difference in Ghostscript versions between OS revisions.

[See this question for some tips and analysis of another environment.](https://serverfault.com/questions/381013/shell-command-slow-when-using-pipe-fast-with-intermediate-file/381048#381048)

You'll want to break this down into steps. The `lp` job submission is fine, but you want to understand where the ghostscript process breaks down. I also work with high volume unattended production printing from Linux servers, so sometimes this is a case of optimizing workflow, the source document  or in extreme cases, downgrading ghostscript or hand-compiling.

You need to see where this is hanging. `strace` will tell you that. But you can also see if a `pdf2ps` or something like that is in place. Please obtain the versions of ghostscript from the old OS and the new.

Comment: Look into switching to Poppler (versus Ghostscript) or pre-processing/converting your documents in your print workflow.

Comment: Ok, it looks like it's not working. The printers are rejecting the postscript generated by pdftops, and even after using CUPS with ghostscript to print PDFs, they are taking a long time to print on the printers themselves (up to two minutes, versus a few seconds).

Comment: Is your application generating PDF files or Postscript?

Comment: The application generates PDFs.

Comment: Well, the difference is that your OS switched to Ghostscript from Poppler between versions. I'm not sure what the appropriate workaround is.

Comment: I thought that on Squeeze the default was ghostscript. Is there a way to simulate what Squeeze does?

Comment: I think the bug was introduced in a later version of poppler. I'm using an older version from Squeeze, compiled on Wheezy. It seems to work properly.